# How can I trigger email script by cell value change?

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am using Google Forms to run a customer database. When the costumer called me, I am editing the same Google Form entry. So I would like to find out how this change or entry of a particular cell can trigger the mail script which I will post here. It should only trigger once, in the moment of change.

Edit:

I have add the "if" now, and set the trigger to Form Submit. Now, if I am changing in the Google Form the value to "test" and sent the form a email is sent to me. But how can I specify this for each entry if I have several email address in the form. Also that it does not send double?

```
function sendArticleCountEmails() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName("Test"));
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange("A2:F4");
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  var currentValue = sheet.getRange("J2").getValue();
  if (currentValue == ("test")) 
  for (i in data) {
    var rowData = data[i];
    var emailAddress = rowData[1];
    var recipient = rowData[0];
    var message1 = rowData[2];
    var message2 = rowData[3];
    var parameter2 = rowData[4];
    var message3 = rowData[5];
    var message = 'Dear ' + recipient + ',\n\n' + message1 + ' ' + message2 + ' ' + parameter2 + ' ' + message3;
    var subject = 'Your article count for this month';
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
  }
}
```

Comment: When you say `I have several email address in the form` what do you mean? Where are the email addresses stored? Also, when you say `not send double`, under what circumstances would the script send double?

Comment: Have a look to this sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YeejRy3B_z3xdVl-23Ty42Xh7mmpltHndJdhi_PSqDk/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Maybe it would be enough when the `if` works on change and trigger the send, but how can I specific it on for each row?

Answer (score 2):

#### Answer:

*It is not possible to send an email on the change of cell in a Google Sheet. You can however send emails on form submission.*

#### Simple Triggers:

As per the Google Apps Script documentation on Simple Triggers:

> The `onEdit(e)` trigger runs automatically when a user changes the value of any cell in a spreadsheet.

However, triggers also have certain restrictions:

> They cannot access services that require authorization. For example, a simple trigger cannot send an email because the Gmail service requires authorization, but a simple trigger can translate a phrase with the Language service, which is anonymous.

#### Submitting a Form:

You can still use the `GmailApp` library in Apps Script to send emails, and specify multiple to send to. If, as in your example sheet, the email addresses are all in column B:

```js
var emails = []
var addresses = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange('B2:B').getValues();
var list = [];
for (var i = 0; i < addresses.length; i++) {
  if (addresses[i] == "") {
    break;
  }
  if (list.indexOf(addresses[i][0]) > -1) {
  }
  else {
    list.push(addresses[i][0]);
  }
}
```

and then edit:

```
var emailAddress = rowData[1];
```

to be:

```
var emailAddress = list[0];
```

This will send the email to all the email addresses listed, though skip duplicates that are in the Sheet.

#### References:

- [Simple Triggers - `onEdit(e)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite)
- [Simple Triggers - Restrictions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#restrictions)